# How to change the url when an AJAX post is done, without page reload

Tags: jquery, django, url, blogs

I am building a blog application in Django and in that any user registered on my site can write a blog. When I was building the model, I choose to represent each blog by the combination of user.id and title as slug field. So a blog titled My Blog of a user with id 8909 would be as

```
/blogs/8909/My-Blog/
```

A problem comes in when I try to provide a `preview` button to the user. The function of preview is to update the blog in the database and open the blog in a new tab. However since I represent a blog by it's title, if the user alters the title, then I need to alter the current url as well, otherwise the url becomes non-existent at the back-end.

I have not come across a way I can edit the url, I have only come across articles that tell I can edit the hash field, but nothing more than that.

What can be the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Give each blog an id that is invariant and use this in your routing eg:

```
/blogs/{userId}/{blogId}
```

This way your resource identifiers are not tied to anything that a user can change.

If however, there is no way to do the above, you may consider storing a list of recently changed titles and issuing a redirect response if any 'out of date' resources are requested.

Comment: Yes I have finally resorted to that only, actually the thing is that I have recently started django development and when I saw the existing apps they all had the same way of making the url using the slug field, so I started out on that.... But now I have learnt it the hard way

Answer (score 0):

#### If you are doing it asynchronously and you dont want to postback the page you can try  window.history.pushState, it can change the URL without post back, but remember at the backend you also have to change the database where you are maintaining actual URL. You can find "How to change URL withought page postback :
" here some details, hope it works for you

http://arbtech.co.in/search_blog.aspx?q=How-to-change-URL-withought-page-postback-: